# Create a popover-like control in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, one of my favorite things about iOS/ObjC in general is the "popover" control.
I am building an app in C# WinForms that would benefit greatly from this type of control- anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to emulate this type of look?

For reference, here's an example screenshot of what I'm talking about https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F05D.png

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple popup control by following the articles linked below

- [Simple Popup Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control)

Answer (score -1):

I *don't think* such a control exists in .Net. What I would do from this point if I were you is try to making one using a customized windows form on top of it. Play with the Mouse Hover events of the control and make the form appear for a short time. Make it without borders. With a little imagination you can have your own version of the PopOver.

Comment: Aye, that's what I think I'll probably have to do (and indeed am working on now), but I figured if anyone knows it'd be Stack Overflow.